# In Python, how can I call copy.deepcopy in my implementation of __deepcopy__()?

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I'd like to create a class which can provide a list of attributes which are not deepcopied by `copy.deepcopy()`. For example like this:

```
class CustomDeepcopy(object):

    a = SomeSimpleObject()
    b = SomeBigObject()

    def dont_deepcopy(self):
        return ['b']

    def __deepcopy__(self,memo):
        #Somehow call copy.deepcopy(self) and have it  
        #deepcopy self.a but not self.b
        #
        #For example, this *almost* works, 
        for attr in self.dont_deepcopy():
            val = getattr(self,attr,None)
            if val is not None:
                 memo[id(val)]=val
        return copy.deepcopy(self,memo)
```

The problem is that I don't think I can call `copy.deepcopy()` from within `__deepcopy__()` because that leads to an infinite recursion (since `copy.deepcopy()` first checks if my object has a `__deepcopy__()` method). Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Why are you calling `deepcopy` with `self` as the first argument?

Comment: Since I want the `__deepcopy__()` method to return a deepcopy of `self`, modulo the small change that I'm not deepcopying `self.b`.

Comment: `deepcopy` takes only one argument. Are you shallow copying them instead?

Comment: `deepcopy` actually takes two arguments, the first is the object to be deepcopied, the second is the `memo` which is alluded to in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) but otherwise undocumented. If you look at the source code, its a dictionary mapping id's of objects to the object, for objects which have already been copied. It serves exactly the purpose I want here, preventing deepcopying of certain objects.

Comment: Great question -- have a very similar problem: quick check on an object to see I can do a very rapid deepcopy substitute; if not, then do the normal deepcopy.  Sad that it's not really possible as described.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you implement a special method (like `__getattr__`, `__deepcopy__`, `__str__`, etc.) You either need to go up the mro with super or use some subset of the original.

I'm not totally clear how you're memoizing attributes, but I'm going to simplify your example. Let's say you always use the same a (and that it's immutable and doesn't need to be copied), but otherwise, you want to copy b. (and you can pass `a` and `b` directly to the constructor to make a new object.

```
class CustomDeepcopy(object):
    def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
        if a:
            self.a = a
        if b:
            self.b = b

    a = SomeSimpleObject()
    b = SomeBigObject()

    @property
    def dont_deepcopy(self):
        return ['b']
    @property
    def deepcopy_attributes(self):
        return ['a']

    def __deepcopy__(self,memo):
        new_kwargs = dict((k, getattr(self, attr, None)) for attr in self.dont_deepcopy)
        for attr in self.deepcopy_attributes:
            new_kwargs[attr] = copy.deepcopy(getattr(self, attr, None))
        return self.__class__(**new_kwargs)
```

Comment: The problem with going up the MRO in this case is that the deepcopy code is in the static method `copy.deepcopy` rather than in `object.__deepcopy__`.

Otherwise the answer you give is a good workaround, but I was hoping to just be able to use deepcopy.

Comment: @marius check out the answer now, it should cover what you're looking for (or at least explain how to work it)

Comment: Thanks. The problem I see with this solution is that it relies on the __init__ constructor remaining the same. I'd like to allow someone later down the line to override it with something completely different, and not rely on the fact the constructor taking a specific form.

Comment: @marius this relies on the `__init__` constructor allowing the same kwargs as the attributes on the body. Anyone can subclass this class and, so long as it accepts kwargs and pushes kwargs to super class, it will work. Otherwise, you could create a separate method like `_constructor` and use that to construct your instance.

Comment: "Anyone can subclass this class and, so long as it accepts kwargs and pushes kwargs to super class, it will work" You're right, I guess I was just hoping to not even put the requirement of pushing kwargs to super on anyone subclassing this. This might be the only way though.

Comment: @marius that's a relatively low bar for a user of your class (esp b/c it's a relatively common idiom to do `super(MyKlass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`).

Comment: In fact, passing kwargs is strongly recommended: http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 1):

`copy.deepcopy` will only call `__deepcopy__` if the method exists - we can avoid this by saving the value of `__deepcopy__`, calling `copy.deepcopy(...)`, and then restoring the value of `__deepcopy__` before returning the result:

```
class CustomDeepcopy(object):

    a = SomeSimpleObject()
    b = SomeBigObject()

    def dont_deepcopy(self):
        return ['b']

    def __deepcopy__(self,memo):
        for attr in self.dont_deepcopy():
            val = getattr(self,attr,None)
            if val is not None:
                 memo[id(val)]=val
        deepcopy_method = self.__deepcopy__
        self.__deepcopy__ = None
        result = copy.deepcopy(self,memo)
        self.__deepcopy__ = deepcopy_method
        return result
```